# After Boolean still see the wireframe

Tags: modifiers

I can still see the vertices still there after I use boolean union? What other way I can join different models and have them merge beside Control J? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please edit your question and provide more info or clearer screenshots of what is happening or what you want to achieve. It's not currently clear what you are asking.

Comment: I merged 3 differnet obj using Join and boolean union. Yet the model still showing all the vertices inside, what is the the best way to combine them?

Comment: If you want to eliminate the geometry inside Booleans are the way, but your shapes must be clean, closed, manifold, watertight meshes; without any overlapping geometry, duplicated vertex or gaps for it to work well. There is no other way, as far as I know